# Determine if two paths are on the same filesystem

Tags: rust

Given two `Path` structures, how can I determine if they are on the same file system?

I need to move a file using `std::fs::rename`, but I only want to perform the rename if the source and destination are on the same filesystem (otherwise, the rename is bound to fail).

In bash, I'd use `stat -c "%d" PATH`. Rust has `std::fs::metadata`, but it [doesn't seem to return the fsid](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html).

Comment: [`MetadataExt::dev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#tymethod.dev) (not cross-platform, however)?  Or you could of course simply attempt the rename, and handle the error?

Comment: If you check before renaming you introduce a small [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) error. As a rule of thumb, it's usually better to just perform file system operations and let them fail rather than attempt to predict the outcome before trying.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, yes, but if I check for it, I can give the user of the program a more useful error message.

Comment: You can [inspect the system error code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.raw_os_error) to determine the reason that a rename attempt has failed.  On POSIX systems, attempting to rename a file to a location on another filesystem will fail with error code [`EXDEV`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.101/x86_64-apple-darwin/libc/constant.EXDEV.html) “*cross-device link*”.

Comment: In my application, there may be 15 minutes (and even hours) between starting it and the need to move a file. So it would give very bad user experience to have it run for a long time only to fail due to an error which could easily be detected up front. The answer given initially by eggyal works well, by the way -- thanks.

Comment: It’s reasonable to sanity check the configuration on startup, but you’ll still need to handle the possibility of this error being thrown when you attempt the rename (eg because some other filesystem has since been mounted along one of the paths: the possibility of this having occurred increases with time, so with delays of 15 hours after the initial check a TOCTOU error is bound to happen eventually).

Answer (score 0):

Based on eggyal's comment: The following worked:

```
use std::os::unix::fs::MetadataExt;
// ...
let path1_meta = fs::metadata(path1).unwrap();
let path2_meta = fs::metadata(path2).unwrap();

if path1_meta.dev() != path2_meta.dev() {
    panic!("Directories need to be on the same file system");
}
```